# Gstreamer WebRTC: sending already encoded h264 stream freezes

Tags: android, webrtc, gstreamer, h.264

I have a h264 stream coming from android. I want to use it as a webrtc video track and display it on the browser. I am using the following pipeline:

```
webrtcbin name=sendonly bundle-policy=max-bundle tcpclientsrc host=127.0.0.1 port=27183 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 ! sendonly.
```

It works and I can see the video stream playing on browser but the stream is very laggy. It completely freezes for 7 to 10 seconds and then I can see the movement for 1-2 seconds and then it freezes again for 7 to 10 seconds and the cycle continues.
If I use my webcam stream or videotestsrc then It runs very smoothly on the browser. How can I make it smooth?

Comment: Try sending it over udp instead of tcp! Certainly, that would make it smoother.
Also, have you checked if your source is encoding fast enough?

Comment: @lnogueir  Sorry for late reply. I am using a third party tool that is sending me this stream through TCP, I cannot change it to UDP but it is encoding fast enough thats for sure. Originally, this tool used this stream to display a video on a local window and it works very fast, 1080p with 60 fps without any issue. But I want to send this stream through webrtc as a video track to display it on the browser. Previously, I used webrtc data-channels to send this stream to the browser and used H264 decoder (Broadway decoder) to decode it and it works fine, but now I want to use webrtc video track.